# new to android - understanding the use of OutputStreamWriter in web service calls

Tags: java, android, web-services

I have been going over the [following tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123) and came across this code which I do not understand the purpose of:

```
              URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
              conn.setDoOutput(true); 
              OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
              wr.write( data ); 
              wr.flush();
```

I don't know what is the purpose of the above code and where is it writing this data to...

From what I could gather, the documentation states that it converts character to bytes... but then it writes it to some where... not sure why this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically used for turning a character stream into a byte stream.

The byte streams and character streams are incompatible for linking as the first one operates on 8-bit ASCII characters and the other on 16-bit Unicode characters. To link them explicitly, two classes exist in java.io package, `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter`.

`InputStreamReader` links a byte stream, with the character stream `BufferedReader` (on reading-side) .

Whereas with the `OutputStreamWriter`, the characters of 2-bytes are encoded (converted) into bytes of 1-byte (`InputStreamReader` does it other way – bytes to characters).

For a Java program to interact with a server-side process it simply must be able to write to a URL, thus providing data to the server. It can do this by following these steps:

```
1.Create a URL.
2.Retrieve the URLConnection object.
3.Set output capability on the URLConnection.
4.Open a connection to the resource.
5.Get an output stream from the connection.
6.Write to the output stream.
7.Close the output stream.
```

Now in the snippet you provided ,

```
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
```

> creates an output stream on the connection and opens an
>   OutputStreamWriter on it--Step 5 If the URL does support output, then
>   this method returns an output stream that is connected to the input
>   stream of the URL on the server side — the client's output is the
>   server's input.If the URL does not support output, getOutputStream
>   method throws an UnknownServiceException.

And

```
wr.write( data );
wr.close(); 
wr.flush();
```

> It writes the required information to the output stream and closes the
>   stream. The data written to the output stream on the client side is
>   the input on the server side.

Comment: what would be considered the "input on the server side" here ?

Answer (score 1):

It's writing it to the output stream of the [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) - which is basically used for the body of an HTTP request (assuming it's an HTTP URL, of course).

Comment: but i looked through this code, that wr object is not being used anywhere

Comment: so i guess my follow up questions is, based on what you wrote, why is all that important ?

Comment: @user3134565: Well it's used in the code you've shown: `wr.write(data)`. That's providing data for the body of the request.